# CSS selector for the next element of an element which fires onclick?

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs

I have an element which listens to the onclick event. It calls a function once it was clicked. After that element is a < dd > which I want to select in a CSS selector. The element which is clicked, is a < select >. How would I do that?

This is the HTML:

```
<select onclick="myFunction();">...</select> 
<dd>...</dd>

function myFunction() {
    // What do I have to write for the ??????
    $$('?????? dd').toggle();
}
```

Note: There are many of those select/dd combination, so I really have to get the next dd after the firing element.

Comment: use `change` for `select` rather than `click`

Comment: No, I want on click, thats ok.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, is `toggle();` plain javascript?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, ok. Thanks for being alert and correcting.

Comment: @Sergio: Good of you to try to help, though, the OP **really** should have tagged it correctly themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimal change is: Pass `this` into your function:

```
<select onclick="myFunction(this);">...</select>
```

...and then:

```
function myFunction(select) {
    $(select).next().toggle();
}
```

`$` enhances the element, then you can use [`next`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/next/) to move to the next element. If you like, you can use `.next('dd')`, but in your case the `dd` **is** the next element.

That still uses `onxyz` attributes, which is a bit old-hat. You might consider hooking things up via [`observe`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/observe/) instead.

Comment: @redreggae: That's not my call. That's the OP's call.

Comment: @redreggae: Feel free to pass judgement if you want. A lot of people still prefer the simplicity of the DOM0 stuff. **I** don't, but again, it's not my call. In any case, I did add a note.

Comment: I reversed my vote..I think it is useful to downvote if the answer don't use the best practice. There will be many people reading the accepted answer and they will do it in the same way. It's the same if somebody using `mysql_*` functions and you don't tell him to better use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

Comment: @redreggae: It's a matter of opinion whether `onxyz` attributes are *always* not best practice. But let's not get into a discussion about it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you mean this:

```
this.next("dd");
```

(specifying `dd` so when there's an error in the mark up, no other element is selected)

If you are trying CSS selectors only, try the following:

```
$("select + dd").toggle();
```

**Note**: this will toggle all `dd`s that follow a `select`.

**Note 2**: apparently this does *not* work in [Prototype](http://jsfiddle.net/KLuhM/) but it *does* work in [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/KLuhM/1/).

See T.J.Crowder's comment:

> [This doesn't work in Prototype] because $ in Prototype looks up elements by ID. $$ is more like
>   jQuery's $, but what it returns doesn't do set-based operations like
>   jQuery does (or rather, not the same set-based operations as the ops
>   you can do on individual elements; you have to use invoke).

`next()` works on both [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/next/) as [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/next/).

Comment: Thats jQuery, isnt it?

Comment: Yes. And you tagged your question as such.

Comment: Nah, somebody else did it, in my case its Prototype. But as I see, they have a next as well.

Comment: @user1856596 I am not familiar with Prototype, but apparently it's the same selector `.next()` that should work.

Comment: *"this will toggle all dds that follow a select."* No, it won't select anything, because `$` in Prototype looks up elements by ID. `$$` is more like jQuery's `$`, but what it returns doesn't do set-based operations like jQuery does (or rather, not the *same* set-based operations as the ops you can do on individual elements; you have to use `invoke`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder When I first answered this question, it was only tagged jQuery. Making adjustements now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$(this).next("dd").toggle(); --> this is Jquery


$(element).next("dd").toggle();
```

see the link [Element.next](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/next/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>...</select> 
<dd>...</dd>

$('select').change(function(){
   $(this).next("dd").toggle();
});
```

Comment: oops sry..i didnt know you wasnt using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Better use unobtrusive javascript, so your js is better coupled from html markup.

HTML:

```
<select><option value="test">Test</option></select> 
<dd>Test</dd>
```

JS:

```
//Event.observe(window, "load", function() {
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    $$('select')[0].observe('click', function(event) {
        var next = event.element().next();
        next.toggle();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/St6Hv/1/)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes thanks..I'm not into prototype, but window load is how jsfiddle do it.